# Receiving Twilio 31201 error, despite having well-formed token

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm using the following code from the Twilio Programmable Video Javascript Quickstart Guide, trying to Initialize the SDK with an access token:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/identity

```
// Create an AccessManager to manage our Access Token
var accessManager = new Twilio.AccessManager('$TWILIO_ACCESS_TOKEN');

// Create a Conversations Client and connect to Twilio's backend
conversationsClient = new Twilio.Conversations.Client(accessManager);
conversationsClient.listen().then(function() {
    console.log('Connected to Twilio!');
}, function (error) {
    console.log('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
});
```

But before even hitting the "could not connect to Twilio" error message designed into the above code, I get the following console error:

**twilio-conversations.min.js:91 Client ERROR r {_errorData: Object, name: "LISTEN_FAILED", message: "Gateway responded with: 31201 Unknown authentication error"}**

I'm testing this on an https-enabled development server, via ngrok.io.  I've followed the code in the tutorial (link above) carefully.  Does anyone understand what causes this cryptic 31201 error?

Comment: Could you post your code that generates the token on your server?